# StringBuilder and Append is not working in C#

Tags: c#

```
        string myString = "  That summer we took threes across the board  ";

        StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            myString.Append("--");
            myString.Append(i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(myString);
```

C# is not allowing me to use StringBuilder or .Append if someone can help out a newbie that would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As mentioned by Dai, you can not have two local variables with the same name. If you look at the compile errors you would see that it says "A local variable or function named 'myString' is already defined in this scope"

Comment: The next time you ask a question, it's best not to phrase it *"C# is not allowing me to use StringBuilder"*. Instead, say something like *"In the code I'm showing, I'm getting error CS1234, 'Blah, Blah, blah' on the line that has the name `myString` defined the second time"*.

Answer (score 3):

- Both your `string` and `StringBuilder` have the same name: `myString`.
- You cannot have two locals with the same name in C#.

Rename your `StringBuilder` instance to `sb`:

```
string myString = "  That summer we took threes across the board  ";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    sb.Append("--");
    sb.Append(i);
}
Console.WriteLine(sb);
```